# encoding character issue

Tags: trigger, calendar

We have certain accounts in the org which contain "\" in their names. Also, there is a 3rd party mobile application which is being managed in the org for visit record sync,upload and download purposes. However, when you schedule visit from the calendar with such accounts and download them to mobile app and complete, sync the records it gives the error "An Invalid XML character (0*0) found in the element content of the document".

We saw that in online, for such visits the subject line is being created with additional space of characters and if you remove them by pressing backspace for 2 times, then the subject line gets corrected and accordingly the error is removed. However, the same issue did not happen for any accounts containing forward slash /.

Please suggest

Comment: I notice you are using the 'trigger' tag. I don't see anything trigger related in the description of your problem. Is the problem with your code, or only with the mobile app? `\` is an escape character. It appears, something parsing data in the app is objecting to that.

Comment: Hi,the trigger is used for creating a visit object from the event. The problem seems to be in online code. The reason is in our org the users can schedule and sync visits entirely in the mobile app without going to salesforce calendar and in such scenario the issue never occurs with such accounts.